# Why will my image not expand to the full size of the div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I'm currently trying to make my website responsive. The way my site is laid out is that on the desktop version it's 2 col-6's, side by side, and each page of my section of my site (a one page site) takes up 100% width and height, aka the size of 1 page. To scale the images, each col-6 had 100% height, and likewise my background-size is set to 100% size. This works great for the desktop version.

The problem is that when I scale down to tablet or phone, where I use col-12's for each half page, in which I stack them on top of eachother, instead of side by side, the 100% sized image div is way too big on a tablet, and squishes out the other div (since section height is only 100%). And on mobile it's way too small, so it shows a bunch of empty space under the image.

I feel like the only way to get it to scale properly is by having no height set on the container, with an img tag used in the div instead of a background image, since it will only take up as much space as it needs, and not any extra. The problem however is that now it's not filling up the entire image div that it's inside, leaving empty space on the side's and bottom. I've tried setting different sizes, settings, etc, but no matter what I do it won't fill it up. It does the same thing on tablet and mobile as well. How can I get this to work?

What it should look like on desktop (this is with background image) - http://i988.photobucket.com/albums/af6/jtbitt/24-inch-desktop-responsive_zps6mwocx8l.png

What it looks like on desktop (with img) - http://i988.photobucket.com/albums/af6/jtbitt/desktop%20version%20with%20img_zpsirzeqjy7.png

Tablet (with background image) - http://i988.photobucket.com/albums/af6/jtbitt/tablet-stacking-improperly_zpsrxkz3ky3.png

Tablet (img) - http://i988.photobucket.com/albums/af6/jtbitt/tablet%20version%20with%20img_zps2lgo5d4x.png

Mobile (with background image) - http://i988.photobucket.com/albums/af6/jtbitt/mobile-stacking-improperly_zps604fz2oy.png

Mobile (img) - http://i988.photobucket.com/albums/af6/jtbitt/mobile%20version%20with%20img_zpsqmqrw2ib.png

HTML -

```
<section id="about" ng-controller="aboutController">    
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row about-row">

      <div class="about-left col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <img src="assets/images/jay-ocean.jpg" class="col-xs-12"/>
      </div>

      <div class="about-right col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="about-content">
          <div class="about-content-title">
            <h1><strong>I'M JAY.</strong></h1>
          </div>

          <div class="about-content-info">
            <p ng-if="about.firstParagraph">An entrepenurial minded, Full Stack Developer. Whenever I'm up against a challenge that I care about, it gives me a rush. Focusing on the big picture is important to me, but I never forget the smaller details. Anything that is not challenging is boring, and makes me yawn. Anything that is seemingly impossible interests me a lot. I'm ready to get to work.</p>

            <p ng-if="!about.firstParagraph">Currently seeking a Javascript position, using the MEAN stack, in New York City. Being innovative, ambitious, and hard working are values that are very important to me. I want to join a company that has similar values and has goals of reaching ridiculous levels of success, not just modest realistic ones. I love working with a solid team.</p>
          </div>

          <div class="about-button">
            <button ng-if="about.firstParagraph" class="label label-success" ng-click="about.switchParagraph()">MORE =></button>
            <button ng-if="!about.firstParagraph" class="label label-success"><a href="/portfolio">VIEW SKILLS</a></button>
          </div>

          <div class="about-personal-info">
            <h4>Email: jaybittner@gmail.com</h4>
          </div>

          <div class="about-icon">
            <a href="{{ profile.url }}" ng-repeat="profile in about.profiles"><img ng-src="{{ profile.icon }}" /></a>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

CSS -

```
#about {
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,97,65,1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,97,65,1) 0%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 7%, rgba(36,123,85,1) 22%, rgba(0,97,65,1) 53%, rgba(34,121,84,1) 76%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 90%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(0,97,65,1)), color-stop(7%, rgba(54,135,95,1)), color-stop(22%, rgba(36,123,85,1)), color-stop(53%, rgba(0,97,65,1)), color-stop(76%, rgba(34,121,84,1)), color-stop(90%, rgba(54,135,95,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(54,135,95,1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,97,65,1) 0%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 7%, rgba(36,123,85,1) 22%, rgba(0,97,65,1) 53%, rgba(34,121,84,1) 76%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 90%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,97,65,1) 0%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 7%, rgba(36,123,85,1) 22%, rgba(0,97,65,1) 53%, rgba(34,121,84,1) 76%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 90%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,97,65,1) 0%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 7%, rgba(36,123,85,1) 22%, rgba(0,97,65,1) 53%, rgba(34,121,84,1) 76%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 90%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,97,65,1) 0%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 7%, rgba(36,123,85,1) 22%, rgba(0,97,65,1) 53%, rgba(34,121,84,1) 76%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 90%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#006141', endColorstr='#36875f', GradientType=1 );
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #101010;
}

/*#about .container-fluid, #about .row {
  height: 100%;
}*/

/*.about-left {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('../../images/jay-ocean.jpg'); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 110%;
  border-right: 3px solid #101010;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}*/

/*.about-left img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: fill;
}*/

.about-right {
  padding-top: 24vh;
  padding-left: 3.4vw;
  text-align: center;
}

.about-content {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.about-content-title {
  padding-bottom: -30px;
}

.about-content-title h1{
  font-size: 3.1vw;
  margin: 3px;
}

.about-content-info p {
  font-size: 1vw;
  word-spacing: 0.3vw;
}

.about-button button {
  color: gray;
  border: 1px solid #101010;
  background-color: #101010;
  font-size: 0.7vw;
}

.about-button a {
  color: gray;
}

.about-personal-info h4 {
  font-size: 1vw;
  word-spacing: 0.3vw;
}

.about-icon img {
  height: 3.5vh;
  width: 1.75vw;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #101010;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Please visit this link. [Here is a recent answer that can resolve your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46841648/make-all-images-in-mat-card-image-same-size-but-scale-correctly/46979731#46979731)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set `background-size` property with `cover` value?

Comment: Just tried this^. Works great on the desktop version, but doesn't scale when I look at mobile or tablet. Here's what it looks like on mobile right now.

http://i988.photobucket.com/albums/af6/jtbitt/background-size%20cover_zpswc6knbqg.png

The other issue is that if I use a background image, I need to set a div height (.about-left) at 100%, and that kind of ruins the design when it's on tablet or mobile, considering the image is smaller than 100%. My .about-right div which is supposed to go below gets obliterated.

Comment: If I change the .about-left size to say 50%, it looks good on mobile. Seems to get this way to work I would need a way for the percentage of .about-left to decrease as the screen gets smaller. Is there a dynamic way to resize the div?