# Make all images in mat-card-image same size but scale correctly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular-material2

This usually isnt a problem but just Material 2 is very under-documented atm so im having trouble making all images the same size but properly resize with window change

All the images I have were pretty similar in size when I created then but one was abit longer height wise, but my old code just adjusted that with some bootstrap calls.

But using the image in a mat-card it is a longer length and thus looks out of place shown here:

[image]

The BAC calculator's image is longer than the rest so it looks out of place and pushes others out of proportion under it or forces an empty cell, here is my call for displaying these:

```
<div *ngIf="data;else other_content">
    <div class="row">
      <div *ngFor="let project of data" class="col-md-6">
        <div>
          <mat-card class="mat-elevation-z4">
            <mat-card-header>
              <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
              <mat-card-title>{{project.title}}</mat-card-title>
              <mat-card-subtitle>{{project.category}}</mat-card-subtitle>
              <div class="grow-empty"></div>
              <div *ngIf="project.source">
                <button mat-raised-button (click)="openSite(project.source)">SOURCE</button>
              </div>
            </mat-card-header>
            <img mat-card-image src="{{project.image}}" alt="{{project.title}}">
            <mat-card-content>
              <p>
                {{project.detail  | slice:0:250}}...
              </p>
            </mat-card-content>
            <mat-card-actions>
              <button mat-raised-button>Information</button>
            </mat-card-actions>
          </mat-card>
        </div>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

If I set the height as a static like '300', it technically fixes the issue but rescaling will just ruin it

I want it to be a set scale like it is, but take any image and scale it up/down to sit and be an appropriate size for the card itself (like Callum.Tech card for example)

Comment: Not sure i get the issue fully, what is the BAC image the profile picture? and in which div class are you displaying it?

Comment: The bottom right image, its bigger than the others due to me having it bigger, I want them all the same sort of size

Answer (score 21):

Just add this style reference in your code.
 If you want to apply this styles to all your cards in the view, add to your style file:

```
mat-card img{
  object-fit: cover; /*this makes the image in src fit to the size specified below*/
  width: 100%; /* Here you can use wherever you want to specify the width and also the height of the <img>*/
  height: 80%;
}
```

Another solution to this issue may be using the class of bootstrap "img-responsive". [Here is a brief description](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_images.asp)

Comment: This still causes the image to be bigger than the rest im afraid

Comment: This helped me fix a completely unrelated issue, so have a candy :)

Comment: The img-responsive is a great tip!

Answer (score -1):

Just add css-class to the image and and style the image from the SCSS file.

```
<img mat-card-image class="imgs src="{{project.image}}" alt="{{project.title}}">
```

Now in SCSS:

```
imgs {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

And for more to Information visit W3school.com/image.